# Detecting PowerShell ISE from command-line process

Tags: .net, powershell

Is there an official or more generic way to detect that your process is running inside ISE than examining the parent process tree?

(Context: I have a command-line utility in development that re-runs itself with elevated permissions. The technique for having it use the same console window as its unelevated parent works fine for console windows, but obviously breaks if the utility is run from ISE - and so, I want to detect this situation and have it fall back to running in a separate window and pausing to permit the user to read the output.)

Further clarification: the utility in question isn't a script. I need to be able to detect if I'm running inside the ISE from a plain.NET 4.5 .exe.

Comment: Further clarification: the utility in question isn't a script.

I need to be able to detect if I'm running inside the ISE from a plain.NET 4.5 .exe.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My answer is off-base and I deleted it to make sure people don't assume this question is answered. Might help to add the clarification to the question itself.

Comment: Good thought, have done.